# System-wide aliases

Tags: bash

I have my aliases set in my `~/.bash_aliases`, it works like a charm in terminal. Howerver, it doesn't do the same with Application Finder `Alt + F2` or Whisker Menu. Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

I put this line `alias codeblocks='GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light codeblocks'` into my `~./bash_aliases` so my codeblocks launchs with light theme when it runs in terminal. Then, I press `Alt + F2` and type codeblocks, it runs without light theme as runs in terminal.

Comment: Can you post a sample? Add to your question, please.

Comment: I put this line " alias codeblocks='GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light codeblocks' " into my ~./bash_aliases so my codeblocks launchs with light theme when I run it in terminal. Then, I press Alt + F2 and type codeblocks, it runs without light theme as in terminal.

Comment: Related: [Keyboard shortcuts in CLI as aliases or scripts](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/550593), [Create an alias or shortcut command to run programme in ubuntu](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/403557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heading for your question is misleading because the problem which you describe is not related to shell aliases, but rather how your system handles the applications which are installed.

The freedesktop.org system of [Desktop Entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) is what you are looking for.

You referred to "Whisker Menu" (an application launcher for Xfce), so it's likely that you're using the Xfce desktop environment. One of Xfce's [goals](https://www.xfce.org/about) is "adherence to standards, specifically those defined at freedesktop.org". So, instad of altering the PATH variable, making wrapper scripts, etc. You could use this standard to create a user-specific or system-wide "Desktop entry" to override the gtk theme for any specific application.

Three steps to add a custom entry for codeblocks:

1. copy the provided system desktop entry file `/usr/share/applications/codeblocks.desktop` to the directory `~/.local/share/applications`
2. edit `~/.local/share/applications/codeblocks.desktop`, adding the environment variable `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light` after the `Exec` key, such that the line reads:

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light codeblocks %F
```

3. build a mimeinfo.cache file for this directory by executing the following command: `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications`

Or it can all be done in just ONE step with:

```
desktop-file-install --dir="$HOME/.local/share/applications" --rebuild-mime-info-cache --set-key=Exec --set-value='env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light codeblocks %F' /usr/share/applications/codeblocks.desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash aliases are only invoked if you run bash, so what you tried won't work. Create a script that runs your aliased command, and put it in a directory that's at the top of your $PATH; $HOME/bin, for instance. You may need to log out first, but it should work.